# Hanging delete request

Tags: python-3.x

Below returns all the info for the dashboards belonging to vhost 'test'

```
import requests
url = 'https://abcde/api/dashboards
headers = {'vhost' : 'test'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('user' , '1234'))
print(r.text)
```

Now I would like to delete all the dashboards but what I have below hangs for minutes until I break out of it. The dashboards are still there viewed from the UI. I have no baseline as to how long a delete should take.

```
import requests
url = 'https://abcde/api/dashboards
headers = {'vhost' : 'test'}
r = requests.delete(url, headers=headers, auth=('test' , '1234'))
print(r.text)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using Postman, I received a 500 error

While the server was building the response a unexpected internal server error occured which forced the server to abort the request